# What is this genre of music called (medieval chanting + rock)?

Tags: identify-this-genre

Refer to this video: [Grain - Kuniaki Haishima](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n86hgIXc1BM) (used in the opening to the *Monster* anime)

What is this genre of music called and where can i find more of this?

Comment: Sounds like a mixture of a Gregorian Chant and Industrial type music.

Comment: I don't know in detail. But with all the guitar and bass, it's definitely some kind of Rock genre.

Answer (score 1):

You're better off looking into experimental composers/producers , I don't think there's an established genere specifically for this but there are a lot of japanese composers (that usually work in anime) that create similar types of music where there's chanting and upbeat rock or modern instrumentation . I can give some names that come to mind (but they may not sound exactly like this sorry) : Kalafina , Yoko Kanno , Susumu Hirasawa , Kenji Kawai

Comment: It's a tricky one, because heavy metal and various other "metal" genres will sometimes blend chant in for atmosphere, or use elements sounding like chant similarly

Comment: Elfen Lied and Akira soundtracks may be of interest (vaguely).